# Upgrading react-scripts breaks this

Tags: reactjs, this, upgrade, react-scripts

The following code works well with `react-scripts@1.1.4`

```
/* file auth.js */
class AuthService {
  ...
}

// export a singleton
export default slug => {
  if (!this._authService) this._authService = new AuthService(slug)
  return this._authService
}
```

I just upgraded to `react-scripts@2.1.1`, and I get `this` as `undefined`.

Wonder how could upgrading `react-scripts` change the notion of `this`

Comment: Your `this` in slug points to global scope. So there's no identifier or parent hierarchy so eventually it will be `undefined`. It's not the problem of `react-scripts`.

Comment: but seriously, it is working with react-scripts@1.1.4 ... breaks if i upgrade to 2.1.1

Comment: @MeetZaveri, how is it undefined? Open up a clean .js file, do `console.log(this)`, what does it print?

Comment: prints undefined

Comment: for one thing .... use-strict may necessitate this to be in a scope. Does react-scripts@2.1.1 forces use-strict?

Comment: Sounds fishy.

`foo.js` > `'use strict'; console.log(this);` > `{}` (node v11.1.0)